# How can I deploy to a specific app with heroku docker:release?

Tags: heroku, docker

Using the [heroku docker:release](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/introduction-local-development-with-docker#release) command, how can I specify which app to release to? I can't see from any documentation whether there's any switch for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku commands take their context from the directory you are in when you run them.

Go into the directory from where you did `heroku create` then run `heroku docker:release`.

If you haven't used `heroku create`, then you can specify the app name with the `--app <APP NAME>` command line parameter. for instance, if you were to release to the app named `f00` you would type:

```
heroku docker:release --app f00
```

Comment: Thing is I haven't used `heroku docker:init`, I've built a Heroku compatible image myself. How does `heroku` even detect its context? I can't find any documentation about this.

Comment: Also, doesn't your approach require calling `heroku docker:create` in order to create and thus specify an application to deploy to? That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: in that case add `--app <app name>` to the `docker:release` command